# Which word is equivalent to word Providing?

Tags: word-choice

Can you tell me which word is equivalent to **providing** in this sentence below, *if* or *in case*?

> The deposit is refundable when you leave, **providing** you haven't damaged anything.

Comment: @ Truong Ha: I remove "which" from before "is refundable", because what you had wasn't a *sentence* - it was just a *noun phrase*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers actually it was a longer sentence and I just copied the clause of it. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OP's context, **providing** is equivalent to **if** (it can validly be replaced by **if**, but not by **in case**).

---

If some statement **S** depends on the hypothetical scenario **X** being true (or false, as in **not X** or **!X**)...

> **S** [is true/will happen] **if X**
>    **S providing X**
>    **S so long as X**
>    **S as long as X**
>    **S unless (!X)**

Note that OP's "hypothetical" is already negated *(you have **not** damaged anything)*. If we remove the negation, it becomes **!X**, so an equivalent to OP's statement would be...

> The deposit is refundable when you leave, **unless** you have damaged anything.

---

If some action **A** is only being taken to *avoid* the possibility of **X** being true (or to deal with issues that will *only* arise if **X** is in fact true)...

> **A lest X**
>    **A in case X**

For example,...

> Don't damage anything, **lest** you lose your deposit.
>    We ask for a deposit **in case** you damage anything.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, the word *providing* means "on the condition." In other words, if you haven't damaged anything at the end of the lease, you will receive your security deposit back.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I would use the word **assuming**.

"The deposit is refundable, **assuming** that you have not damaged anything.

Comment: how about *admitting*? It seems to me this word carries a good contrast here, more than *assuming*.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Either is fine. The difference is largely a matter of taste.